# Powershell String Expansion Conundrum

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Very simple concept, need to create Exchange OPATH recipient filter syntax from variable.

```
$rf = { ((Company -eq $company_name) -and (Alias -ne $null)) }
```

Company name is a simple string.

When trying to run     `Set-AddressList` command, I receive a     `Cannot bind parameter 'RecipientFilter' to the target, Invalid Filter Syntax` error

I have tried many ways of concatenating string and variables, but it seems that Exchange isn't expecting a normal string for this RecipientFilter parameter, if I convert a working filter to a variable-based concatenated string, all stops working

Comment: "*I have tried many ways of concatenating string and variables*" - really? Because your code is a scriptblock, not a string at all...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! According to [this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998847(v=exchg.160).aspx), -ReceipientFilter *is* supposed to accept a string. I wouldn't be surprised if Set-AddressList does syntax validation on that string, but a string is a string is a string.

$rf, as you have it defined above, isn't a string, though - it's a ScriptBlock. Here's what I ran:

```
$Company = "Contoso"
$Alias = "*jerry*"
$rf = { (($Company -eq "Contoso") -and ($Alias -ne $null)) }
$rf | Get-Member
```

Encasing the **$rf =** assignment in single quotes gets us a string:

```
$rf = '{ (($Company -eq "Contoso") -and ($Alias -ne $null)) }'
```

I don't have an Exchange environment to test on, though. If that doesn't work for you, could you provide the full Set-AddressList command to diagnose?